# Matrix addition: combinations of elements that sum up to a specific value

Tags: python, loops, matrix

## using Python,

I have two matrices A and B of size 100,000x25 and a vector C of size 25. 
I know for loops are slow so I want an efficient way of adding every combination of numbers from A with B and C and collecting all indices of those elements that sum greater than 10. 
Small Example for demonstrating

```
   _____
```

A =

```
  [1, 2 ]
  [5, 8 ]
```

B =

```
   [3, 6]
   [4, 2]
```

C= [3,4,7,1]

In the above example, A[0,1]+B[0,0]+C[0] = 5+3+3 =11 which is what I am trying to find I.e all combinations that sum upto a specific value. 
I tried for loops but takes way long. And my estimate is almost 2 days for the matrices that I have. Any suggestions?

Comment: Converting them to sorted lists may work, so you can, for example, if `A[i] + B[j] + C[k] <= 10` then you can ignore any combination of `Ai`, `Bj` and any `C[n]` with `n > k`.

Comment: My first thought is to try to avoid computing all sums.  For example, if any of the numbers is greater than 10, then its index is valid in combination with all the other indices (assuming all number are nonnegative.)  Can you tell us more about the characteristics of your data?  Are they small positive integers as in your example?